# Convert IEnumerable to Collection (not ICollection)

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable

Linq returns IEnumerable and the code has a Collection. How to assign the return value of a Linq operation to a Collection variable?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myList = new List<string> {"item"};
            Collection<string> myCollection = myList.Select(x => x);

            foreach (var item in myList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. About not using Collection, I can't change it.
2. Assigning List to Collection throws casting error.
3. The following works somehow, any better alternative?

`Collection<string> myCollection = new Collection(myList.Select(x => x).ToList());`

Comment: `= new Collection<string>(myList)`?

Comment: Why do you want it to be an Collection? Why not just change the type of `myCollection` ?

Comment: Why you have to use `Collection`? If you do `.ToList()` it gives you the `List<string>` and it is also `ICollection<string>`

Comment: An `ICollection<string>` makes some sense (and every `List<T>` is already an `ICollection<T>`); a `Collection<string>` far less so, as, while `Collection` *can* be used on its own, it's intended as a base class for other, specialized collections. As a type it should only very rarely be used directly (basically only because someone else has already done so and you have no choice).

Comment: What is the actual use case? In general I would recommend sticking to arrays and `List<T>`, or the `IEnumerable<T>` / `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`/ `IReadOnlyList<T>` interfaces. Or one of the more specialized collections like `HashSet<T>`, `Dictionary<T>` etc.

Comment: About not using ICollection<T> it is not up to me so I can't change it. Assigning List to Collection throws casting error.

Comment: "it is not up to me so I can't change it" - you can provide more context though... mysterious and counterintuitive requirements with no context aren't really helpful on Stack Overflow. And I'd personally always consider it worth pushing back on them internally, too. Even if the requirement doesn't change, understanding the reason behind it can help to find the best way of meeting it.

Comment: And point 3 shows that you've already *got* a solution - what are you looking for from an alternative? It's very hard to know what you'd consider to be a useful answer here...

Comment: `new Collection(....ToList())` is fine. Note specifically that `Collection` documents it *wraps* the list, it doesn't copy the elements, so while this is still overhead compared to having a `Collection` directly, the overhead is minimal (in terms of memory, at least -- in terms of speed you may pay a penalty because such access isn't necessarily JIT optimized the way accessing a `List` directly could be). Avoiding it means writing a tedious `foreach` loop.

Comment: @JeroenMostert doesn't Linq return a new IEnumerable instead of modifying it or returning the same one? And then I expected that new Collection, created that, a **new** Collection, shouldn't it?

Comment: In your *specific* example (where you start off with a `List`) you of course don't need LINQ at all, just `new Collection<string>(myList)` will do -- if you don't mind the wrapping behavior. In *general*, if you only have something enumerable, `new Collection(...ToList())` adds little to no overhead compared to the alternative (creating a new `Collection` and adding each element individually). Since you've given no details on how the `Collection` is to be used it would be hard for anyone to tell what the most appropriate thing to do is -- only you know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *have to* work with `Collection<T>` why not implementing an *extension method* in order to use it with *Linq*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

...

public static partial class EnumerableExtensions {
  public static Collection<T> ToCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
    if (source is null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    Collection<T> result = new Collection<T>();

    foreach (T item in source)
      result.Add(item);

    return result; 
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as simple as

```
var myCollection = myList
  .Select(item => item) //TODO: Put actual query here 
  .ToCollection();
```